# What might cause Alt+Tab to get stuck half-way?

Tags: release-freya, plank, gala, games

Here is a video demonstrating the issue: https://youtu.be/FImJp1gqaeg

I've mostly observed it in connection to full screen applications/games such as Factorio, Dota 2, etc.

#### Questions

1. What might be going wrong? Can this be an issue with elementary's gala/plank? Or something else?
2. Is this a known issue? I've tried searching for **elementary OS <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> bug** and similar keywords, didn't find anything. Have anyone of you encountered it before? It is very much reproducible on my system, so I'd be happy to open a bug report and/or give further details on the issue that can help tracking it down.

Any answers, help, pointers are greatly appreciated. I like using elementary OS as my main OS and hoping that finding a fix for this will make that an even smoother experience.

## Misc details

elementary OS 0.3.2 Freya

Comment: I encounter quite often with games. Kerbal, minecraft and Tabletop sim.

Comment: There does seem to be a few bugs lodged with similar issues. [This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gala/+bug/1528150) looks like the most relevant. Although In my case I always find alt tabbing a few more times will get me back to the game or a desktop.

Comment: @elmato That indeed seems quite like what I am describing! Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: Is it any different if instead of using Alt+tab you put the game on another workspace and use ⌘+leftarrow? (I know this is not actually a solution to your problem, but it may help people debug the issue).

Comment: Okay, so I did a quick test and here are the results: While switching workspaces seems to be working okay, if I leave the full screen game on screen #2 and try to use #1 as a regular screen, when alt tabbing between even the non-fullscreen apps get stuck just like I showed in the video.